# Error when trying to delete user

Tags: 7, flags, heartbeat

I installed the [heartbeat module](https://www.drupal.org/project/heartbeat/issues/2063519) to track user activities on my website. It took me hours to configure it but everything seemed to be working as I wanted until I tried to delete a test user from the website. I was wondering if anyone is familiar with this error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'etuncel_drup4.drup_flag_content' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM
>   {flag_content} WHERE (content_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND
>   (content_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1,
>   :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3,
>   :db_condition_placeholder_4)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => heartbeat_activity [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 20097 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 20098 [:db_condition_placeholder_3]
>   => 20101 [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => 20102 ) in HeartbeatFlagPlugin->activityRemoved() (line 106 of
>   /home/public_html/sites/all/modules/heartbeat/modules/heartbeat_plugins/includes/heartbeatflagplugin.inc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an error with the module but someone developed a patch for it.

Here;

https://www.drupal.org/project/heartbeat/issues/2102743